# jOOQ agregate function over multiple tables

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, jooq

we have a `MAINTABLE` which stores records. The records can be connected to child elements inside `CHILDTABLE1` and `CHILDTABLE2` by foreign key inside the child tables.

The API allows to receive a list of objects from `MAINTABLE`. These list can be sorted with different strategies like alphabetic, etc. One sorting strategy orders the objects from `MAINTABLE` by newest child element.

As example: Return projects (`MAINTABLE`) sorted after the newest events inside these projects (`CHILDTABLE1` and `CHILDTABLE2`).

For this I want to have a field with the max value from the `CHILDTABLES`. The field can then be used in the "order by" statement from the `MAINTABLE` if the users wants to use this sorting strategy.

Idea:

```
// field with the highest creation date of any child element
Field<Object> maxDate = DSL.select(DSL.max(
                DSL.select(CHILDTABLE1.CREATION_DATE)
                .from(CHILDTABLE1)
                .where(CHILDTABLE1.FK.equal(MAINTABLE.ID))
                .asField()
                .union(
                   DSL.select(CHILDTABLE2.CREATION_DATE)
                  .from(CHILDTABLE2)
                  .where(CHILDTABLE1.FK.equal(MAINTABLE.ID))
                  .asField()
                )
        )).asField("maxDate");

// main query over MAINTABLE which orders by maxDate of any child element
List<Record> queryResults = jooq.select(*)
   .select(maxDate)
   .from(MAINTABLE)
   .orderBy(maxDate)
   .fetch();
```

This query does not work, because `maxDate` can not be computed. I wanted to create a new field for `maxDate` to keep the main query tidy and also because the "order by" statement will be filled dynamic from another method. This other method does not know new created fields inside the main query, but can have access to the `maxDate` field.

Any advice would be nice.

Comment: From the way you phrased your question, I'm assuming you would like to get the `MAX(CREATION_DATE)` from the union between `CHILDTABLE1` and `CHILDTABLE2`. But what do you want to do with that `maxDate`? I mean, what's the relation to the `MAINTABLE`? Maybe, could you support your use-case with some example data and a more meaningful "main query"?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The main query returns a list of objects, in my case projects. The projects have the child elements tasks and members. Projects, tasks and members have all CREATION_DATE fields. The API for receiving the projects list has different order strategies like alphabetic, etc. Most order strategies are easy and just use one column in projects. But in this case I want to implement an order strategy for projects which orders after newest event inside projects. So that the project list starts with projects in which new user or task where created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Let's look at how to write this query with SQL, first.

From what I understand, you want to fetch data from `MAINTABLE` sorted by the most recent corresponding entry in either `CHILDTABLE[N]`. This could be done as follows:

```
SELECT maintable.*
FROM maintable
JOIN (
  SELECT fk, max(creation_date) max_creation_date
  FROM (
    SELECT fk, creation_date
    FROM child_table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fk, creation_date
    FROM child_table2
  ) child_tables
  GROUP BY fk
) max_creation_dates
ON maintable.id = max_creation_dates.fk
ORDER BY max_creation_dates.max_creation_date DESC
```

There are other ways to solve this, of course, e.g. you could be using window functions or `CROSS APPLY` depending on your database.

#### Translating that to jOOQ

That's the easy part. In jOOQ you can store derived tables in local variables prior to using them in an "outer query". I'm going to reuse the same names as before:

```java
Table<?> childTables = table(
   select(CHILD_TABLE1.FK, CHILD_TABLE1.CREATION_DATE)
  .from(CHILD_TABLE1)
  .unionAll(
   select(CHILD_TABLE2.FK, CHILD_TABLE2.CREATION_DATE)
  .from(CHILD_TABLE2)))
  .as("child_tables");

Table<?> maxCreationDates = table(
   select(
     childTables.field(CHILD_TABLE1.FK),
     max(childTables.field(CHILD_TABLE1.CREATION_DATE)).as("max_creation_date"))
  .from(childTables)
  .groupBy(childTables.field(CHILD_TABLE1.FK)))
  .as("max_creation_dates");
```

And then, you can use the derived tables in your actual query:

```java
using(configuration)
  .select(MAINTABLE.fields())
  .from(MAINTABLE)
  .join(maxCreationDates)
  .on(MAINTABLE.ID.eq(maxCreationDates.get(CHILD_TABLE1.FK)))
  .orderBy(maxCreationDates.get("max_creation_date").desc())
  .fetch();
```

The above implies you have this static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: Two notes:
1) instead of `maxCerationDates.get(..)` I needed `maxcreationDate.find(...)`
2) I also included the `CREATION_DATE` of the `MAINTABLE` in childTables. To make the code look more clean I did `.unionAll().unionAll()...` instead of `.unionAll(.unionAll(...))`.